# How do I make an expandable box with CSS and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: I should have specified that I want it to be animated, and retractable. So why isn't the + sign moving with the rest of the box? And why isn't it animated? I have the transition CSS.

I know this has been asked before, but I tried writing my own, and it's just... not working. Check the jsfiddle to see what I mean.

I'm not trying to use too much Javascript. All I use it for is to toggle the state of the menu. Everything animation needs to be CSS. Now, the only thing confusing me is *why* this doesn't work?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjhph51u/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="expandbox" expanded="false">
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" disabled></input>
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" disabled></input>
<button type="submit" disabled>go</button>
</div>
<a href="#" id="plus" onclick="expandBox()">
+
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
//expand top box
var box = document.getElementById("expandbox");
function expandBox(){
    if(box.getAttribute("expanded")=="false"){
        box.setAttribute("expanded","true");
        box.style.height="100px";
        box.style.display="block";
    }else{
        box.setAttribute("expanded","false");
        box.style.height="0px";
        box.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
#expandbox {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    height:0px;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.5s;
    transition:height 0.5s;
    -o-transition:height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:height 0.5s;
}
```

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you function is a local variable in the anonymous function assigned to `window.onload`. Change you fiddle options at: Frameworks & Extensions to `No wrap - in <body>`. This way the function will become global, and you can call it just fine.

Comment: Awesome! Now my only issue is the actual animation. Why is the + disappearing and why isn't it animating?

Comment: There is no animation between `display: none` and `display: block`. As it makes no sense whatsoever. First, change it to `display:block`, then animate between opacity 0 and 1.

Comment: What about between height? I set height:0px then height:100px

Comment: Oh man you just solved my problem. Thanks! But what about this little +? Why isn't it moving?

Comment: It is because the position of you div is fixed. You should wrap your anchor with another div, and try to order them as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the HTML & JS code as below and it's now working fine. Give it a try!!

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="expandbox" expanded="false">
        <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" disabled></input>
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" disabled></input>
        <button type="submit" disabled>go</button>
</div>
<a href="#" id="plus">+</a>
```

**JS Code:**

```
//expand top box
var box = document.getElementById("expandbox");
function expandBox(){
    if(box.getAttribute("expanded")=="false"){
        box.setAttribute("expanded","true");
        box.style.height="100px";
        box.style.display="block";
    }else{
        box.setAttribute("expanded","false");
        box.style.height="0px";
        box.style.display="none";
    }
}
document.getElementById("plus").onclick = expandBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
$('#plus').click(function() {
   $('#expandbox').toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: I do not want to use jQuery as it is not required for this kind of stuff. Thanks anyway!